# jQuery - Submit Form to PHP and Generate In New Window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, pdf

I'm using Gravity Forms 1.8.5 on a Wordpress 3.8.1 with Woo Commerce 2.1.5 and would like to add a second button to the product page that runs a PHP script that generates a PDF using fPDF. I've used jQuery to rewrite the function of the button with the ID previewButton to run the PHP (code included below). However, I would like the PHP to generate the PDF in a new window. Also, with the way it is now, the PDF is generated in the same window and when you go back to the page with the form, the "Add To Cart" button is disabled. I attempted to capture the Form Action with the first few lines of the code below, but it is not working. Could anyone help with either of the issues?

1 - the PDF is generated in a new window

2 - the Add To Cart button works after viewing the PDF

You can view a sample of the product page at:
http://www.ortorderdesk.com/product/prepare-for-your-closing-copy/

My code for the jQuery I'm using to rewrite the buttons is:

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var form = jQuery('.cart');
var originalFormAction = form.attr("action");

jQuery("#gform_submit_button_1").on("click", function(){
jQuery(this).parent("form.cart").attr("action",originalFormAction).submit();
});

jQuery("#previewButton").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var sku = jQuery(".add_to_cart_button").attr('data-product_sku');
var preview = 'http://www.ortorderdesk.com/proofs/' + sku + '.php';
jQuery(".cart").attr("action", preview);
form.submit();
});
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't have an anchor tag that calls your php file to a new window?

```
<a href='http://www.ortorderdesk.com/proofs/12345678.php' target="_blank" >Preview PDF</a>
```

My fake **1234578**, I presume, is the product key which you may be able to generate on the server side php when the page is loading.

The target=_blank will open the called page in a new window, separate from your main page and you may find that your cart button works if the JQuery is removed.

All of this depends though on whether you can pre-generate the sku(**12345678**) from php on page load.

Alternatively use JQuery to update the href on the fly using .attr

Comment: Thanks! That's a step in the right direction.
However, it opens up two windows and the Add To Cart button, unfortunately, still didn't work. 
Since I already had the first and third lines of your code in mine (they are the last two lines), so I added it in between. Or should I have put all three of your lines in my code somewhere?

Comment: The form data is pulled by the PHP to populate parts of the PDF that is generated. The user inputs their location, address, etc. and that information is retrieved by the PHP scripts and plugged into the PDF.

Comment: Thats fine, you just need to populate the correct SKU on the link and the called PHP file will take care of the rest. See my updated answer about changing the sku on the href dynamically

Comment: Hmmm... it doesn't seem to populate the user's form submitted data.

Comment: Your View Proof button works this way if you look at the html. You need to copy this for your proofs PHP if you can access the code <a href='http://www.ortorderdesk.com/proofs/397288.php' target="_blank" >Preview PDF</a>

Comment: I think the button allows the data the user has entered to be passed through to the form. If you look at the link in my original post you'll see that I added the link as you describe but when you fill out the form and click it, those fields do not show up in the PDF as they do when you click the button.

Comment: Ah, it's because it's a form post and the anchor isn't doing this. Contact me on my bio if you would like to continue the conversation offline as SO will complain. I may be able to help you out privately.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to contact you... Haha... I don't have enough reputation to chat. My e-mail is in my profile.